# Non-controller ng-click function not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an simplification of my actual issue.

When button is clicked it's parent is meant to have a red background. The function is not a controller function, it's just a simple view thing. This works as expected when the button is NOT in a directive. However when used in a directive it doesn't work. I know this is a scope issue, and it's a simple solution, but I'm a knobhead.

I've seen solutions to a similar issues but all those are when the click function is controller based.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/NZPSejy6vh2n4gYETHuX?p=preview

Angular stuff:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.boxes = [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
  ];


});

app.directive('box', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'box.html',
    scope:{
      makeRed: '@'
    }
  };
});
```

View:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="box-wrapper" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{redbox: isRed}">
      <box 
          make-red="isRed = !isRed"
      >
      </box>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Directive Template:

```
<div class="box">{{$index + 1}}</div>
<button ng-click="{{makeRed}}">Click me</button>
```

Styles:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.box-wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.redbox {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's a scope issue.

To use the same scope as the parent, you have to set the scope to false in your directive, like this: `scope: false`.

Since you access the parent's scope, you can also modify it. The template box.html then becomes :

```
<div class="box">{{$index + 1}}</div>
<button ng-click="isRed = !isRed">Click me</button>
```

**EDIT**

Using `=` also works has it was suggested.

The directive becames:

```
scope: {
    makeRed: '='
}
```

The initialisation of the directive:

`<box make-red="isRed"></box>`

And the directive template:

```
<div class="box">{{$index + 1}}</div>
<button ng-click="makeRed = !makeRed">Click me</button>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EReOf4NMZ2IpMjRnIRVN?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this.  The problem is my actual problem, my directive looks like this: http://pastie.org/10306471

Comment: OHHH, now I get it!  What a knob I am.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to evaluate an expression in the parent from within the directive.

You are currently using `@` with the isolated scope.  This is a one way binding from parent to directive.

To pass an expression, you will use `&`

Working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/2LWeSiOmjNwMmgPwL7P5?p=preview

Angular [$compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

Comment: Thanks Sunil.  The plunker isn't working though so I can't see what you mean.

Comment: Replace the '@' with an '&', i see the plunkr working, does the background not change when you click the buttons?

Comment: Are you looking in the "In a directive – It doesn't work! Why God, why?!" section..the bottom section?  The top section works but it always worked.